# show that $f(r) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{area}(S_r)} \int_{S_r} u^2 dS$ is increasing, when $u$ is harmonic

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, harmonic-functions, divergence-operator

### Heading ##Let $u: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic function. For every $r>0$, I denote:

$$ f(r) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{area}(S_r)} \int_{S_r} u^2 dS $$
when $S_r = \{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2 \}$.

I want to show that $f$ monotonically increasing for $r \in (0, \infty)$.

My problem here is that while $u$ is harmonic, $u^2$ is not necessarily, since $\Delta(u^2) = 2\|\nabla u\|^2$.

So I can't use here the mean-value property. I tried also somehow use the divergence theorem, but I always get a very ugly and non computable integral.

I also tried just calculating $f(r_1)- f(r_2)$, but since those integrals are on different surfaces, I don't see how to do it.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you can do is to take the derivative of $f$ with respect to r and show that it is always non-negative and conclude from this your desired statement. I happy to provide more details if needed.

edit: (details).

First notice that 
$$
\frac{1}{\text{area}(S_r)} \int_{S_r} u^2(x) dS(x) =
\frac{1}{\text{area}(S_1)r^2} \int_{S_1} r^2u^2(rx) dS(x) 
=
\frac{1}{\text{area}(S_1)} \int_{S_1} u^2(rx) dS(x).
$$

Now compute $\frac{d}{dr} u^2(rx)$ which gives $x\cdot\nabla u^2(rx)$, where
$\cdot$ denotes the scalar product. Now, argue why you can swap differentiation
and integration to get

$$
\frac{d}{dr} f(r) = \frac{1}{S_1} \int_{S_1} x \cdot \nabla u^2(rx) dS(x) 
= \frac{1}{S_r} \int_{S_r} \frac{x}{r} \cdot \nabla u^2(x) dS(x)  
= \frac{1}{S_r} \int_{B_r} \Delta u^2(x) dx, 
$$
where in the last step the divergence theorem was used.
Can you conclude from here?

Comment: If you could provide more details it would really help me

Comment: I think I have it: since $u^2(0) \le \frac{1}{area(S_r)} \int_{S_r} u^2 dS$ then $u^2(0) \le f(r)$ and taking a derivative will get $0 \le f'(r)$

Comment: May I asked how do you know that $u^2(0) \leq \frac{1}{\dots} \int_{S_r} \dots dS$? Because actually I would use the above reasoning to conclude this.

Comment: You can prove it by using the mean value theorem for harmonic functions and Cauchy-Shwartz inequality for integrals

Comment: Ah, okay. In general then, the above reasoning holds for any function that fulfills $\Delta u \geq 0$, that is, when $u$ is by definition _subharmonic_. (Just to build a bridge to the other comments). Another point for me is, that it is not obvious that $f$ is differentiable, or is it? In any case, I hope this was helpful.

Comment: It was helpful indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have that $u^2$ is subharmonic, so it satisfies the mean value inequality

$$u^2(x) \leq \frac{1}{area(S_r)}\int_{S_r} u^2 dS$$

for each $x$ in its domain within the sphere.

Comment: Thanks, but i never heard the term subharmonic, and thus, never saw this inequality. So I am looking for a different answer

Comment: @GabiG You can prove it for yourself, and you have already proven this property if you have done the proof for the Mean Value Property for harmonic functions, as this inequality was half of that proof, or at least very similar. Subharmonic just means $-\Delta u \leq 0$

Comment: @GabiG You also do realize that even if you do not quote this property, you could perhaps follow along a proof of that property but with this specific function plugged in, which would get you exactly what you need?

Comment: Did you mean $\Delta u \ge 0$ by any chance? Since in the question $\Delta(u^2) = 2||\nabla u||^2 \ge 0$

Comment: @GabiG Isn't that equivalent to what I said, $-\Delta u \leq 0$? It's written that way because with either Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions $-\Delta $ is a positive definite operator.

Comment: I am sorry, but now I am really confused. Are you talking about the $u$ from my question? I also looked at the definition of subharmonic function in wikipedia, and it doesn't say $\Delta u \le 0$. Could you maybe write the proof to the  inequality you wrote in your answer?

Comment: @GabiG There are minus signs in front of my expressions if you look again. And no, I will not write a proof of that inequality, you are free to look it up in any textbook on PDEs, or any set of lecture notes you can find. I recommend Evans' book.

Comment: Okay, could you please elaborate what to do after I showed this inequality?